# Change the background color of a texview from a list in the spinner in android studio with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I wanted one more time for your help. I'm starting with the android kotlin programming. how can I change the background color of a textview from a list of colors that I have in a spinner

I have created drawable with the colors but I don't know how to select a list color to change the background color of that textview

```
val arrayscolor= arrayOf("#FF03DAC5","#FF414141")
spinner.adapter=ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arryscolor)

spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long
    ) {
        txtmensaje.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(position.toString()))
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
      txtmensaje.setText("")
    }

}
```

I want to mention that I don't know how to put that drawable to my color arrays because I put that color by default, I want to add that how to make the user look at the color and not the exaggecimal number

help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing wrong is that you're converting the `position` to `String` and parsing it as a `Color` which means if first is item is selected, you're parsing `0` to `String` as first item's position is `0` here :

```
Color.parseColor(position.toString())
```

What you've to do is you've to use that `position` and extract the value on that position from the array or the adapter as :

```
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long
) {
    txtmensaje.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString())) 
    //parent is the adapterView and position is the selected item's position.
}
```

Also, you can directly use the colorArray as

```
txtmensaje.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(arrayscolor[position].toString()))
```

You can also do something else which I use in one of my projects :

1. Save the colors in `colors.xml` as resources for easy access.
2. Create a function as :

   ```
   private fun chooseColorAsPerPosition(context: Context, position: Int): Int {
       when (position) {
           0 -> return context.resources.getColor(R.color.color1, null)
           1 -> return context.resources.getColor(R.color.color2, null)
           2 -> return context.resources.getColor(R.color.color3, null)
           3 -> return context.resources.getColor(R.color.color4, null)
           else -> return context.resources.getColor(R.color.defaultColor, null)
       }
       return context.resources.getColor(R.color.defaultColor, null)
   }
   ```
3. Call the function as in `onItemSelected()` as :

   ```
   override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
       txtmensaje.setBackgroundColor(chooseColorAsPerPosition(this@YourActivity, position))
       //pass the context, for activity this or this@YourActivity and position is the selected item's position.
   }
   ```

This helps when you need these values in multiple places, in multiple Acitivites.